# Triggering sequential time triggers with GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to plan something for my website that will send an event to GA4 after 4 minutes, for example, and then repeat it every minute. If anyone has any idea if this is possible with GTM, please tell me. Thank you in advance for the answers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible and it's typically done with the timer trigger in GTM. Or, it's also always a solution to deploy a custom HTML tag and then have a script there doing any timeout you want.

When your first trigger fires, you fire a custom HTML tag, looking something like this:

```
<script>var tempTimeSpentOnPageFlag = 'true';</script>
```

Now make a new variable of the JavaScript Variable type. It's gonna look like this:

[image]

Now in your **second** trigger, you use this var as a reference like so:

[image]

And this should be about it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I just saw your answer and I am writing now.

I created 2 triggers with GTM, one of them is triggered after 3 minutes, only 1 time. This works but the second trigger does not work as I want. I want the second trigger to start after 3 minutes and send an event to GA4 every 30 seconds for example. For this, I select Event and "starts with" from the settings of the second trigger and write the name of the first trigger, but it does not work.

Comment: What you can do here is: when your first trigger fires, you not only do whatever you want on it, but you also deploy a cookie, or, better yet, a JS variable to the global scope of the page. Then in your second trigger that's only supposed to fire after the first one, you add that cookie/JS var as a requirement for it to fire. Ot you can reimplement it similarly in pure JS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have no JS knowledge. I'm trying to do this via GTM. I'm trying to set 2 timers and set the second one to "Starts with the following event" by typing the name of the first trigger, but the trigger does not start.

Comment: add a screenshot to your initial question indicating what you're trying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a timer that will be triggered 1 time after 3 minutes. I want to trigger the second timer after the 3rd minute, for example every minute or every second.

Comment: the event name you're supposed to use there would be the event name variable value that you get from the GTM preview debugger when you click on the event in question on the left of the debugger and then switch to the Variables section to see all variables. But I don't think it will work like you want... Not sure if you can chain them through events like that. And even if it works, I don't see how it will continue firing subsequently, But sure, try it out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The main purpose here is to stop GA4 from receiving data for the first 3 minutes. Normally I can set the time as 30 seconds but I don't want the first 3 minutes to be reflected. I don't know if this is possible via GTM. I want a timer trigger to be triggered by another timer trigger...

Comment: Yep, that's what I've described in my answer. I updated it with a walkthrough. Should be helpful.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I create a custom html tag and make it triggered with the first timer. With the second timer, I reference the javascript variable and write "true" as equals without quotes. When the first timer is triggered in the debugger, the Custom HTML tag is triggered, but the second timer does not start.

Comment: and in the debugger, you don't see any timer events after the first tag fired?

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. The first trigger is triggered after the time I specified and when it is triggered, the CUSTOM HTML tag is also triggered, but the second trigger does not appear in debugging. I am attaching another photo to the first message.

Comment: uh, okay, so JS path it is then. In the custom html tag, instead of setting the variable, you now want to set a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) which would conduct a [dataLayer push](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer), pushing there an empty event, say with the name of `4SecPassed`. Now for the second trigger, you would change the type from the timer to the custom event with the name set to the `4SecPassed`. That's it. This should work better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your efforts. I have removed the old photos and added the new ones.

Some things got mixed up. I don't have JS knowledge and it's been a few days since I started using tag manager:

1) Should I remove the javascript variable?

2)Should I remove the custom HTML tag containing this:

<script>var tempTimeSpentOnPageFlag = 'true';</script>

Slowly, one by one, I want to tell you how I'm doing
I have 2 timers. I will specify their names, trigger times and how many times they are triggered:
every_second6: 4000 ms
(only 1)
every_second: 1000 ms
(infinity)

Comment: I don't know how to provide the datalayer.push function. From the variables, I select "Special Event" as the variable type. to be able to provide the datalayer.push function. I might be doing this from the wrong place. I will post a picture of what I am encountering.

Comment: Ok, we're going too deep at this point. You probably want just to stop and hire a contractor to do the tracking for you. Unless you want to change your career into analytics tracking that is.

Comment: I don't think everything in life is about money. Anyway, I'm not going to discuss it. Thank you for your efforts, take care.